# How can I save HSQLDB in-memory data to file without calling SHUTDOWN statement

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

I set "file:" catalog but it saves in-memory data in that file only after SHUTDOWN statement.
Is there any way to do that without db shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your JDBC connection URL has a `jdbc:hsqldb:file:` prefix, the database is file-based. You can execute the `CHECKPOINT` statement anytime to write the up-to-date data contents to the .script file.

With all database types, including pure in-memory databases with `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:` URL's, you can use the `SCRIPT 'full_file_path_name_to_save'` statement to write the contents to a file of your choice.